# how to import a texture for use on multiple items?

Tags: modeling, texturing, objects

How can I import a texture to no specific object? I need to use a texture on 8 objects. I have 8 blades and I downloaded a metal texture, and want to apply it to the 8 clones the same way each time.

Comment: use the same material , I think you can copy UVmaps

Comment: You don't import it any special way, UV Unwrap one mesh, select all and link UVs (Ctrl+L). Then apply the same material

Comment: yeah but it changes the texture when its imported to a specific object. so how can i not affect the texture while painting it?

Comment: and why is my paint going through the object?

Comment: @AidanPallian I assume you want to paint on the blades to have some variation on the texture?